# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado

I get this error here is my code

```
var query1 = (from cust1 in context2.Clients
              where cust1.ID == int.Parse(textBox1.Text)
              select cust1).FirstOrDefault();`
```

even if my ID is an Int not a string

Answer (score 1):

Call `Parse` method outside of your query:

```
var id=int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
var result=context2.Clients.FirstOrDefault(cust=> cust.ID ==id );
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the simplest solution would be to convert to an `int` before the query:

```
var id = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
var query1 = (from cust1 in context2.Clients
              where cust1.ID == id
              select cust1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, for the sake of error handling:

```
var id = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out id)) {
    // raise an error condition
}
var query1 = (from cust1 in context2.Clients
              where cust1.ID == id
              select cust1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the int.Parse to a variable first, like this:

```
var intValue = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);   
 var query1 = (from cust1 in context2.Clients
                          where cust1.ID == intValue
                          select cust1).FirstOrDefault();
```